# drupal - how to find the file that creates a tag list of articles

Tags: drupal, drupal-taxonomy

I am trying to re-write the code that generates the TAGS page in my DRUPAL 7 install.

http://s199881165.onlinehome.us/transfem/drupal_experiment/druppy3/drupal-7.22/?q=taxonomy/term/1

where do i go to edit the tag list file?

I am specifically interested in the aspect of re-styling the css and restructuring the order of divs.

Answer (score 1):

In drupal 7, you can get vocabulary list here: http://example.com/admin/structure/taxonomy

You will find `tags` vocabulary name on this page. Click `List term` next to it.
It will take you to tags listing page where you can edit terms.

Hope this will help.